Semisimple Lie algebras: general features of ladder operators and towers of vectors
I would like to ask what are the most general results and constraints on the representations of finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebras; I know that one can group the generators into Cartan subalgebra generators and pairs of ladder raising and lowering operators. But what are the general features of the towers of states that one can build by applying raising operators to a reference state? How many reference states and independent towers can one build? I am confused about the features of these towers of states.
Thanks a lot for your help!

I think the best thing here would be to actually have a look at the representation theory of semisimple Lie algebras such as in Fulton and Harris's Representation Theory or maybe Humphreys' Introduction to Lie algebras.
The theory is more involved than I think you are imagining but it is a beautiful and elegant theory.
A very rough overview is that for a semisimple Lie algebra all representations can be decomposed into irreducible representations and those can be broken down into weight spaces. The latter are the common eigenspaces of a chosen Cartan subalgebra (a.k.a. maximally commuting subalgebra diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$). The Lie algebra itself can be decomposed in the same way giving a decomposition into "root" spaces. The elements of each root space (root vectors) act on the weight spaces in a natural way.
In $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ you can call these root vectors, "ladder operators" because the weights of any irreducible representation lie on a line like the rungs of a ladder. In a more general situation though we immediately have more directions to move in. Indeed the dimension of the space of weights is equal to the rank of the Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is the only rank $1$ semisimple Lie algebra.
So we don't have "independent towers" of weights in general but more like a network of them. Indeed all the weights live on what is called the weight lattice. There are ways to count the number of weights in a given representation but this could be quite involved in general.
